# clear spring for GraphQLContext content after request finished

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql-java, spring-graphql

I am using spring boot 3.1.1 to develop GraphQL application, also included spring-boot-starter-graphql, code as below, I want to delete all content from context after the request is done, how can I implement it? Beside GraphQLContext, is there any other way to cache the data? Thanks.

```
public class OrderInfoController {
    private final GraphQLContext context;

    public OrderInfoController() {
        this.context = GraphQLContext.newContext().build();
    }

    @QueryMapping
    public String prepareName(@Argument String orderId) {
        context.put("name", "Darren");
        return " welcome !";
    }

    @SchemaMapping
    public String getName(@Argument OrderInfo orderInfo) {
        context.get("name");
        return "hello darren";
    }

}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on why you're trying to do this? The context object is garbage collected after the request, so there should be nothing to clear.

Answer (score 0):

By default the context is already per-request. You made a separate context that is a field on the controller itself, so it's no different from any other property on a singleton bean (it isn't even managed by Spring). Don't do that. A properly scoped context is already provided to you implicitly, and can be injected into your resolvers:

```
@Controller
public class OrderInfoController {

    @QueryMapping
    public String prepareName(@Argument String orderId, GraphQLContext context) {
        context.put("name", "Darren");
        return " welcome !";
    }

    @SchemaMapping
    public String getName(@Argument OrderInfo orderInfo, GraphQLContext context) {
        context.get("name");
        return "hello darren";
    }

}
```

You could use a [`WebGraphQlInterceptor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/current/reference/html/#server.interception) to execute logic around the request, but it doesn't sound like that's what you need here.